how to use pdfjs worker in react and typescript?
I'm trying to use pdfjs in a react+ts project.
import React from "react";
import * as pdfjs from "pdfjs-dist"

export default function EditPdf() {
  React.useEffect(()=>{    
    const doc = pdfjs.getDocument("helloworld.pdf");
    doc.promise.then((pdf)=>{
      console.log(pdf)
    })
  },[])  
  return (
        <div>
            content
        </div>
    )
  }

Here I import it but I get the error:
Error: No "GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc" specified.
    at get workerSrc (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/pdfjs-dist.js?v=aab08523:12098:11)
    at _PDFWorker._initialize (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/pdfjs-dist.js?v=aab08523:11983:7)
    at new _PDFWorker (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/pdfjs-dist.js?v=aab08523:11956:10)
    at getDocument (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/pdfjs-dist.js?v=aab08523:11120:69)
    at http://localhost:5173/src/EditPdf.tsx?t=1727811223984:24:17
    at commitHookEffectListMount (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-W6L2VRDA.js?v=2bfcffa6:16915:34)
    at invokePassiveEffectMountInDEV (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-W6L2VRDA.js?v=2bfcffa6:18324:19)
    at invokeEffectsInDev (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-W6L2VRDA.js?v=2bfcffa6:19701:19)
    at commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-W6L2VRDA.js?v=2bfcffa6:19686:15)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-W6L2VRDA.js?v=2bfcffa6:19503:13)

Well online it seems "easy" enough... I can do something like:
import pdfjsWorker from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry";

// ...
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker

but pdf.worker.entry doesn't exist. I searched in the node_modules folder and found a similarly named pdf.worker.mjs file. I tried to import with import pfdjsWorker from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry" but it cannot find the declaration for this. Finally I noticed that there exists a pdfjs.PDFWorker type declaration, but I am not sure how to use it (no documentation).
How can I successfully import and use pdfjs + a worker in a React+TS proj?

This worked for me:

Import the package as below
import * as pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist";

Copy the pdf.worker.min.mjs file from node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/ directory into your public folder

Set the worker to point to the file in your public folder
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = window.location.origin + "/pdf.worker.min.mjs";


Helpful articles:
https://medium.com/@hesseclaus/using-pdfjs-with-react-app-rewired-f1f3a2527c45
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/index.html#interactive-examples

You can try grant the workerSrc by //mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.mjs. Please refer to this document: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/

Due to CORS I cannot point it to a remote directory. I tried copying and pasting the code locally but I am not sure how to import it

import * as pdfjs from "pdfjs-dist/webpack.mjs";

Try importing from pdfjs-dist/webpack.mjs
And for typing you can declare module in .d.ts file. Code from my index.d.ts file:
declare module "pdfjs-dist/webpack.mjs" {
  export * from "pdfjs-dist";
}


This gets rid of the errors but results in the promise from pdfjs.getDocument not resolving. I also get the warning: The file does not exist at {proj_path}/node_modules/.vite/deps/build/pdf.worker.mjs?worker_file&type=module" which is in the optimize deps directory. The dependency might be incompatible with the dep optimizer. Try adding it to optimizeDeps.exclude. (x4)
